# Qt Qm file version

Tags: qt5, translation

Qt Translation files (.ts) do have "version" as one of the attributes. This file then gets converted to .qm file which is then used in application for strings translation.

Is there any way to know from qm file that which version of ts it is built from?

Answer (score 0):

This version may be used by Qt toolchain only. I guess to identify the file format. The target 'worker' for QM files is [QTransltor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html) and this class doesn't expose version attribute.

Comment: Right, so it seems there is no way then :(